# How append to a file with certain extension

Tags: bash, scripts

There is a certain file with extension '.log' to which I want to append something. There is only one file with that extension in the folder. When I try

```
(echo "host name:" hostname) >> *.log
```

bash creates a file named `*.log`.  In cases where there are multiple files with that extension, I would like to choose only the one which starts with 'tailor' and ends with '.log'. How can I do these?

Comment: `(echo "host name:" hostname) >> tailor.log` should do it.

Comment: @SorenA OP thinks about something like `tailor[something random here].log`

Comment: the file name could be 'tailor-date-time.log` where date and time changes. so its not simply `tailor.log'.

Comment: So `tailor*.log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A redirection must be unambiguous. You can use wildcards in your redirection provided it resolves to one specific file.

```
echo "Host name:" $HOSTNAME >> *.log
```

will add to an existing .log file provided it is the only .log file in the folder.

- If there are multiple matching files, you will get an error message stating the redirect is ambiguous.
- If there is no matching file, the redirection will create a file with the exact name as provided, i.e., including the wildcard symbols.

That you achieved this last outcome shows that there was no .log file present when you tried the command.

You may narrow the wildcard to be more specific, e.g. in your case, you may use 'tailor*.log' as the mask.

Comment: @Shibli, for your information, right when you accepted my answer, I was editing it  to propose an even  shorter form you may also want to consider

Comment: @steeldriver, you are right. It will work like the OP indicated if there is only a single file matching the expression. Will need to update my answer again.

Comment: @steeldriver: I was editing. Your comment had me to fundamentally revise the answer. Thanks! I was put on the wrong foot by the OP stating he obtained a file '*.log'. That happens if there is not any *.log file in the folder, as opposed to what was suggested in the question.

Comment: Looks good now - upvoted :) You might consider mentioning `shopt -s nullglob` which would result in the shell outputting an error message rather than creating the literal `*.log` file